# Can someone help me with Linear Algebra Questions?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is a translation? For translations in $ \mathbb R^2$
, is it possible for a translation $(⃗) = ⃗ + ⃗⃗$ to be a
linear transformation? Give conditions on $⃗⃗ $ that are necessary and sufficient for $$ to be a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $T$ is linear, then $T(0 x) = 0T(x)$ for any vector $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $T$ is linear, you must have $T(0) = 0$. If $T(x) = x+b$, this reads $$0+b = 0.$$Now what?

Answer (score 0):

A translation is defined as a shift by some constant amount: in $\mathbb{R}^2$ this corresponds to a shift in $x$ and $y$. All linear transformations $T$ satisfy the following: $$T(a\vec x + b\vec y) = aT(\vec x) + bT(\vec y)$$

So let's say $T : \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is in the form of $T(\vec x) = \vec x + \vec b$ for constant $\vec b$. The conditions on linear transformations require that $T(\vec 0) = \vec 0$ (try it). What does this tell us about the value of $\vec b$?

Comment: so b must be zero then?

Comment: Exactly, $\vec b = \vec 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We also require $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$, which in your case gives $x+y+2b\ne x+y+b$, unless $b=0$.